# Counting occurences of character in string from command line

Tags: c

I have a program written in C that should count the occurrences of a character "c" in a string "s".
My problem is that I am getting the error "warning: comparison between pointer and integer if(s[i]==c)"

I'm new to C and am struggling to figure out how to fix my program.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countOccur(char *c, char *s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count=0;
    char* c = argv[1];
    char* s = argv[2];

    count=countOccur(c, s);

    printf("%d", count);

    return 0;
}

int countOccur(char *c, char *s)
{
    int i, count=0;

    for(i=0;s[i];i++)  
    {
        if(s[i]==c)
        {
          count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What type is `c`? How would you get the first character of `c`?

Comment: The type of `s[i]` is `char`. The type of `c` is `pointer to char`. Comparing those makes no sense.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin How would I take in c as a char from the command line? Would I just leave it as argv[1]?

Comment: Replacing `s[i]==c` with `s[i]==*c` or `s[i]==c[0]` should fix the code.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks a lot, sorry for the silly mistake, I'm very new to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check that the program was called the way you expect, or help the user correct the mistake (the user is you next week when you forgot).  As you count the frequency of a single letter, you want to use `char` instead of `char *` for that.  I used `size_t` instead of `int` as the both the `i` and `count` are non-negative.  Also minimized the scope of `size_t i` by moving the definition inside the loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t countOccur(char c, char *s) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if(c == s[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: %s letter string\n", *argv);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%zu\n", countOccur(argv[1][0], argv[2]));
}
```